# I propose the tag [film-analysis]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are several questions asking for interpretations of a movie. For example:

- [In the movie Spring Summer Fall Winter and Spring, why does the master cry?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/35686/13525)
- [Are the movie Fight Club, and Project Mayhem in it, buddhist?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/15617/13525)
- [What are the Tibetan sketches in the movie Samsara called?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/29004/13525)
- And many more if you search for [`movie`](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=movie)

I propose two synonym tags for this: [movie](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) and [film-analysis](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film-analysis). The description of the tag can include this Wikipedia page: [Film analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_analysis)